# PIL image.rotate center(0.0)

Tags: python-imaging-library

I rotate the image 45 degrees to the left corner, using Image.rotate, but the image disappears beyond the border of the frame. How can I fix this?

```
im2 = self.image
rot = im2.rotate(45, expand=True, center=(0, 0))
self.image = rot
```

Originally the image looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhd9y.png)
after a 45 degree rotation like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLTeD.png)

Comment: I think we will need a better code example to get an idea of why this might not be working the way you expect.

Comment: some lines of code just to change the background color (they are not important), the same result will be if you apply this code. in im2 I load the image, I try to turn it, but it goes abroad. This is the best example of the code that I have.

Comment: Can someone then just know how to rotate the image around the left corner?

Comment: Obviously when rotating around the top left corner, the image goes beyond the original borders. What are you expecting, what are you seeing and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Judging from your new picture, the `center=(0, 0)` must mean the origin point of the *frame*, not the image.

To rotate with the top-left of the image fixed, try this:

```
rot = im2.rotate(45, expand=True, center=(im2.left, im2.top))
```

This is assuming that the image has properties that tell you its position within the frame.

<del>You are rotating around the top-left corner `center=(0, 0)`, the origin point for this image. Try using the image center (1/2 width, 1/2 height) as your center of rotation.</del>

Comment: The image povarachivaetsya but the left corner is displaced (that is, it rotates relative to the center), but I need that the left corner would stay in place. If I understood you correctly, did you mean 1/2 * width ...?

Comment: I guess I will need a 'before' image to understand what is going on. The 'after' image that you posted is consistent with your original description, assuming:
 (1) The image was originally centered in the frame.
 (2) The image was rotated clockwise 45 degrees, centered on the top-left corner (0,0)

Comment: I added the image "before", "after", did you mean it?

Comment: What is "left" and "top"?

Comment: I am assuming that the image has left (x) and top (y) properties that describe where the image is located relative to the frame's origin. If the image doesn't have these properties, and there is no function you can call to get the image position within the frame, then I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Have you tried PILLOW? This is a more up-to-date library than PIL, and may work better for you.

Comment: It's the same thing.